# Protecting Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 from DDoS attacks

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have hosted my blog Amazon Web Services S3 (static files with hosting). Should I add any policies or measure to further protect my account from DDoS/high bandwidth consumption?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would argue that it is a concert. Not on the technology side, but certainly on the financial side. If for some reason your content is downloaded excessively from S3, you are paying for it.

If you want the content accessible by all, then there is no S3 policy that can help you.

If you want to track your spending, I suggest using [AWS Billing Alerts](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/). You can use a CloudWatch alert to send a message to SNS (and to your email) once your total bill for the month gets to X dollars.

Comment: Actually you can add a policy to your buckets/objects to prevent access from a malicious user, once you identify his IP(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html), by checking your access logs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Since S3 is only flat files, and already serves [large number] requests per day, you don't (personally) need to worry about DDoS attacks against it. If (on the off-chance) a DDoS is successful, [more people than just you will be impacted](http://status.aws.amazon.com).

Comment: not really a DDoS attack... a malicious script can keep on downloading the files infinite time and thus it can exhaust the get requests and may end up in huge bills.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You're talking about the billing angle. Peter Sankauskas is right in that you want to take a look at billing alerts.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to protect your site from DDoS attack is to setup CloudFlare's free service tier. It will cache and protect your domain name against DDoS free.

[Cloudflare plans](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans-b/)